# Bootstrap Multi-select - adding images after checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Firstly here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/krish7878/sqVD6/11/)

I'm trying to add image after the checkbox for [Bootstrap multi-select](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect) plugin, after each check box or before it I'm trying to add a thumbnail, here's what I did till now:

1. Adding images directly in each option but this plugin removes all html in
2. Used jquery after() to add image after the  field but it does not work.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div id="vm" class="tab-pane fade in  active">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <form action="/Lab/Rtx/etabs/edit/0451483t" id="ServerEditForm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
                <div style="display:none;">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="hidden" name="data[Server][0][id]" class="form-control" value="1" id="Server0Id">
                        <div class="controls">
                            <label for="Server0Vm">hosta0451483t</label>
                            <input type="hidden" name="data[Server][0][Vm]" value="" id="Server0Vm_">
                            <select name="data[Server][0][Vm][]" class="multiselect" multiple="multiple" id="Server0Vm">
                                <optgroup>
                                    <option value="ctrlr0451483t">ctrlr0451483t</option>
                                    <option value="ipr0451483t">ipr0451483t</option>
                                    <option value="ldap0451483t">ldap0451483t</option>
                                    <option value="proxy0451483t">proxy0451483t</option>
                                </optgroup>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.multiselect').multiselect({
        buttonWidth: 'auto',
        numberDisplayed:15,
        onChange: function(element, checked) {
            //console.log(element.attr('value') + checked);
            $("ul.multiselect-container").find("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(){
                //console.log(element.attr('value'));
                var valueAttr = $(this).attr('value');
                if (element.attr('value') == valueAttr) {
                    var checkParent = $(this).parent().parent().parent().hasClass('active');
                    //console.log(checkParent);
                    if (checkParent == false) {
                        $(this).removeAttr('disabled')
                    }else{
                        $(this).attr('disabled','disabled')
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [**`optionLabel`** option](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#configuration-options)

> `optionLabel` A callback used to define the labels of the options

```
$('.multiselect').multiselect({
    enableHTML: true,
    optionLabel: function(element) {
        return '<img src="'+$(element).attr('data-img')+'"> '+$(element).text();
    },
    // ...
});
```

HTML:

```
<select name="data[Server][0][Vm][]" class="multiselect" multiple="multiple" id="Server0Vm">
    <optgroup>
        <option data-img="1.png" value="ctrlr0451483t">ctrlr0451483t</option>
        <option data-img="2.png" value="ipr0451483t">ipr0451483t</option>
        <option data-img="3.png" value="ldap0451483t">ldap0451483t</option>
        <option data-img="4.png" value="proxy0451483t">proxy0451483t</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5b39tatu/2/)

Comment: There seems to be some issue with the fiddle, the source of the image is displayed instead of the images.

Comment: I'm not sure whether the plugin was updated or I missed this somehow. But, there's an option `enableHTML` now, which is set to `false` by default. Setting it to `true`, the plugin will support HTML within options. **NOTE** Please read option description before setting it to `true` : http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#configuration-options JSFiddle updated.

Comment: @ArturFilipiak When I try to unselect its  not working

Comment: It doesn't work because you have set that in your original code... If you want to be able to *unselect* options, remove your `onChange` option. [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5b39tatu/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
$(function() {

  $('#chkveg').multiselect({
    includeSelectAllOption: true,
    enableHTML: true,
    optionLabel: function(element) {
        return '<img src="https://placekitten.com/'+ $(element).attr('data-img')+'"> '+ $(element).text();
    },
  });

  $('#btnget').click(function() {
    alert($('#chkveg').val());
  });
});
```

```css
.multiselect-container>li>a>label {
  padding: 4px 20px 3px 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect/docs/js/bootstrap-3.3.2.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect/docs/css/bootstrap-3.3.2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<form id="form1">

  <div style="padding:20px">

    <select id="chkveg" multiple>
      <option value="cheese" data-img="100/109">AAA</option>
      <option value="tomatoes" data-img="100/108">BBB</option>
      <option value="mozarella" data-img="100/107">CCC</option>
      <option value="mushrooms" data-img="100/106">DDD</option>
      <option value="pepperoni" data-img="100/105">EEE</option>
      <option value="onions" data-img="100/110">FFF</option>
    </select>
    
    <br /><br />

    <input type="button" id="btnget" value="Get Selected Values" />

  </div>

</form>
```